# Python and Azure Service Bus

Tags: python-2.7, azureservicebus

I am having trouble setting up a connection from a Python script to Azure Service Bus. A similar code in C# (on windows) is running fine.

```
from azure.servicebus import *

AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE='blablabla.servicebus.windows.net'
AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ISSUER='RootManageSharedAccessKey'
AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY='sdkfjlkewjrlwerjlewrjlewrjfjflsdkfjew3='

bus_service = ServiceBusService(service_namespace=AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE, account_key=AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY, issuer=AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ISSUER) 

bus_service.create_queue('taskqueue')
```

This results in the following output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "createqueue.py", line 9, in 
>       bus_service.create_queue('taskqueue')
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py", line 143, in create_queue
>       request.headers = self._update_service_bus_header(request)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py", line 860, in _update_service_bus_header
>       ('Authorization', self._sign_service_bus_request(request)))
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py", line 868, in _sign_service_bus_request
>       self._get_token(request.host, request.path) + '"'
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py", line 908, in _get_token
>       resp = self._httpclient.perform_request(request)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/http/httpclient.py", line 191, in perform_request
>       self.send_request_headers(connection, request.headers)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/http/httpclient.py", line 170, in send_request_headers
>       connection.endheaders()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 818, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 780, in send
>       self.connect()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
>       self.timeout, self.source_address)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
>       for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
>    socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

What is going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of the Python SDK are you using and when did you create your SB namespace?

Comment: Good question: do not know since I just pulled up the pip package like 2 days ago. I also tested with Python on Windows with the SDK pulled from MSDN using the WebInstaller. Same result. Oddly I have a working script creating a blob storage container. I also tested with a pre-provisioned queue and just wrote a message. This also results in the same error behavior.

Comment: I have the same problem, without solution yet. Not working from Windows machine nor Linux machine using python, but works with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

```
AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE='blablabla'
```

You don't need to specify the entire URL for the namespace.

Comment: This was also my idea however with or without the namespace the result is the same. I have also run a python script creating a blob storage container and it was working (with and without adding the URL).

Comment: Are you using SAS or ACS?

Comment: SAS. See use of access key. Again: same concept worked flawless in C# / .NET

Comment: Ah ok. I don't think the Python SDK has support for SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connectivity with servicebus service on microsift.
I had the same problem and the issue was with wlan0 connectivity - I've lost my IP assigned by DHCP server. 
Or your DNS is not working as should.